# Http Response Header in java

Tags: java, servlets, httpresponse

Hi I am sending Http Request using HttpClient . I am able to call the Servlet but returning `405 status code.doPost method not allowed` . tried get also same status code.

And also i am not able to get The Header in response. Do i need to forward or include the request back to Request.

//Code to Send Http Request

```
public void perform(Date now, long remainingRepetitions)
    {
        log.info("Starting the Job " + now);

        System.out.println("Before try 2");
        try {

            HttpResponse response;
            while(true){
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                System.out.println("Http Client instantiated");
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/Servlet");
                System.out.println("Post Request created");
                response = client.execute(request);
                System.out.println("Http Status Code  = " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() );
                Header headers[] = response.getAllHeaders();
                for(Header h:headers){
                    System.out.println("New" +h.getName() + ": " + h.getValue());
                }

                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200 || response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 405){
                    if(response.getLastHeader("JobStatus").equals("Success"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            log.info(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            log.info("Exception Occured");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            System.out.println("finally");
        }
```

// Servlet

```
private void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside ProcessReqest");
        try{
             //some method call
             resp.addHeader("JobStatus", "Success");

        }catch(Exception e){
             resp.addHeader("JobStatus", "Failure");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share the `Servlet`?

Comment: Is "Inside ProcessReqest" getting printed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Servlet implements only `doGet().` When you are calling `POST` method, either `doPost()` or `service()` method should be implemented by the servlet.

By default, when the servlet's service method is called, it calls the corresponding `doXXX()` method. If that method is not implemented by the subclass of HttpServlet, the `doXXX()` method in HttpServlet returns `405 Method Not Supported status code`.

The snippet of doPost() method in HttpServlet is below:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
         throws ServletException, IOException {

         String protocol = req.getProtocol();
         String msg = lStrings.getString("http.method_put_not_supported");
         if (protocol.endsWith("1.1")) {
             resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, msg);
         } else {
             resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg);
         }
```

I think in your case, you have declared `doPost()` method as private. It's access is hidden. Modify it as protected and try.

It is not correct to have weaker access in subclass. Usually, the compiler should have given error when you compiled that servlet.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is protected in code.But still same 405 error. Since i am trying to send the request from one war to another war Another problem I am adding response in Servlet using response.addHeader("JobStatus","Success") . Am trying to read in client java class. But i am getting some garbage value like @1!23ec . Help me. Headers []header = response.getHeaders(); for( header: ) {//prints other other headers like Content type,length etc but not mine added}

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your server doesn't support the POST method. Try using a HttpGet request instead.

POST is used to send data to a server, whereas GET is used to request information. Your code is not attempting to send any data, so I think HttpGet is what you want.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html

Answer (score 0):

If this is code both from your client and servlet, the `doPost` method is private, hence you're servlet will not respond to `POST` requests. Make your `doPost` method public.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the access modifier in your `post` method from `private`. This is why it is not visible. Change the modifier to either `protected` or `public`

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Inside ProcessReqest");
    try{
         //some method call
         resp.addHeader("JobStatus", "Success");

    }catch(Exception e){
         resp.addHeader("JobStatus", "Failure");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the headers added with

```
HttpServletResponse.setHeader(...)
```

or

```
HttpServletResponse.addtHeader(...)
```

are "servlet response headers", not "HTTP headers".

So among them you find also the http headers, but what you set is not received by the client together with them.

I suggest you to use URL parameters instead of headers.